# Play a <video> tag inside an <img> tag

Tags: html, image, video

I'm trying to play a video inside a PNG image of a TV so that the TV serves as a frame for the video.

I tried something like that, but it just pushes the TV image up and plays the video underneath.

```
<img class="tv" src="images/tv.png" alt="Tv">
  <video width="320" height="240">
    <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</img>
```

Can you help me finding my way in there ? Because I'm sure there is an easy solution, but i really don't know where to look. 
Thank you so much !

Comment: have't played with HTML 5 at all, but what if you set the z-index?

Comment: Use the image as background in a wrapper div.

Comment: Safari's latest Technical Preview allows for `<img src="video.mp4" />` https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/MOMezY

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you can't use `<img>` this way, because it's an element which can't contain other elements.

All you have to do is put your image as a background for `div` and then display video with correct position:

```
<div id="tv_container">
    <video width="320" height="240">
        <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>

<style>
#tv_container {
    background: url('images/tv.png') no-repeat top left transparent;
    width: 400px; /* Adjust TV image width */
    height: 300px; /* Adjust TV image height */
    position: relative;
}
#tv_container video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px; /* Adjust top position */
    left: 40px; /* Adjust left position */
}
</style>
```

or instead of `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;` you can use `margin: 30px 0px 0px 40px;` for `#tv_container video` (but trick with `position` is better when you want to add more element into `#tv_container`.

I assumed that TV image is bigger than `video`, but you have to adjust few things to display it correctly.

---

Inspired by Guilherme J Santos' answer, I suggest you to use TV image as layer over the `video`, because in this way you can use image with tv screen which doesn't have to be strict rectangle. Of course part of video will be cropped then, but it will look like tv screen.

```
<div id="tv_container">
    <video width="320" height="240">
        <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>

<style>
#tv_container {
    width: 400px; /* Adjust TV image width */
    height: 300px; /* Adjust TV image height */
    position: relative;
}
#tv_container:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: url('images/tv.png') no-repeat top left transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
#tv_container video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px; /* Adjust top position */
    left: 40px; /* Adjust left position */
    z-index: 5;
}
</style>
```

Be sure `z-index` of the layer (which in this case is `#tv_container:after` pseudo-element) is greater than `video`'s `z-index`. <strike>And there's one thing: your `video` will not be clickable (because it's under the layer)</strike> According to @brichins's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881678/html-play-a-video-inside-an-image/10881895?noredirect=1#comment62355048_10881895) it's also possible to make video clickable under the layer (thanks!).

**Of course screen part of the tv must be transparent!**

Comment: That's perfect man, it works ! 
The video won't be clickable, but it's set on autoplay anyway.
Thank you so much :)

Comment: It's possible to make an underlying video like this clickable - just set `style="pointer-events:none"` on the overlay. Click events will pass right through it.

Comment: The video itself won't be clickable but you can add controls to the bottom of the video to add this functionality. Just add the `controls` attribute to the `video` element: `<video width="320" height="240" controls>`

Answer (score 4):

You can set the image as a background of a div slightly larger than the video. Center the video in the div, and you will appear to frame the video with the image.

```
<div id="video_container">
    <video width="320" height="240">
        <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#video_container { 
    background-image: url('images/tv.png'); 
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
}
video {
    text-align: center;
    /* or
    padding: 30px 40px;
    */
}
```

Comment: It works for the placement of the video. But the video plays over the TV, while i would like it to be behing it.
A z-index doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: `z-index` only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed). See my answer (second part).

Comment: Thank you Wirone, i didn't know that about the z-index.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How would a user see the video if it is under the image?

Comment: It's simple: part of an image is transparent :)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/CNj3A/338/

It consist in a div with a background image. I also set padding atribute, so the borders of the tv image on background will be displayed even with some other element inside the div tvBorder.

Inside you insert any element you want. Could be a `<video>`, other `<div>`, an `<image>` etc.

```
 <div id="tvBorder" style="background-image: url('https://mockuphone.com/static/images/devices/samsung-galaxys4-black-portrait.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; width:625px; height:532px; padding-left:250px; padding-top:150px;">
        <video controls autoplay height="450" width="250" style="object-fit: fill">
            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap embed video inside image:

HTML Code:

```
/* Example 1 */
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="laptop-wrapper">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/f890SC1schE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

/* Example 2 */
<div class="container">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="desktop-wrapper">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/f890SC1schE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

 /* Example 3 */
<div class="container">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-image: url(' http://img01.deviantart.net/05b6/i/2011/030/8/5/apple_led_cinema_screen_by_fisshy94-d38e3o5.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; width:900px; height:758px; padding:80px;text-align:center;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="header-unit">
            <div id="video-container">
                <video autoplay loop class="fillWidth">
                <source src="http://yourwebsite.com/your-video-file.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
                <source src="http://yourwebsite.com/your-video-file.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
                <source src="http://yourwebsite.com/your-video-file.webm" type="video/webm"/>
                Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
                </video>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* 1st example */

div.laptop-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 67.5%;
    height: 0;
}
div.laptop-wrapper iframe {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZNgk.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding: 11.9% 15.5% 14.8%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* 2nd example :  BACKGROUND IMAGE */
div.desktop-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 67.5%;
    height: 0;
}
div.desktop-wrapper iframe {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url(http://img01.deviantart.net/05b6/i/2011/030/8/5/apple_led_cinema_screen_by_fisshy94-d38e3o5.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding: 3.4% 10.8% 18.6%;/* 11.9% 15.5% 14.8% */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* 3rd example :  BACKGROUND IMAGE */
.header-unit {
    height: 150px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-right:none;
    border-left: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}
#video-container {
    position: absolute;
}
#video-container {
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
video {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
}
video.fillWidth {
    width: 100%;
}
```